# Assigning a callbacks to the react ref

Tags: reactjs

Having such a simple `react` `class component`:
import React from "react";

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
  }

  focus() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  myRef2 = (input) => {
    console.log("myRef2")
  }

  myRef3 = (input) => {
    console.log("myRef3")
  } 

  render() {   
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id ="i1"
          type="text"
          ref={(input) => { 
            console.log("myRef1")
            this.textInput = input; }
          } />
         <input
          id ="i2"
          type="text"
          ref={this.myRef2} />
        <input
          id ="i3"
          type="text"
          ref={this.myRef3()} />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focus}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomTextInput
```

what is the difference between this 3 different ways of calling a refs:

1.

> ref={(input) => { console.log("myRef1") this.textInput = input; } }

2. 

> ref={this.myRef2}

3. 

> ref={this.myRef3()}

Is there a difference between the #2 and #3 method? I'm i right that in the #2 case we assign the `myRef2` function to the *ref* while in the #3 case we just call the `myRef3` (parenthesis after the function name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#2 is a correct way of doing this :

```
<input
    id ="i2"
    type="text"
    ref={this.myRef2} />
```

This means ,

```
<input
          id ="i2"
          type="text"
          ref={()=>this.myRef2} />
```

While #3 means that when javascript code is executed , this.myRef3 function is called each time it is read:

```
<input
          id ="i3"
          type="text"
          ref={this.myRef3()} />
```

```
<input
          id ="i3"
          type="text"
          ref={ console.log("myRef3")} />
```